# Raphael setting transparent png opacity loses alpha channel

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, raphael, vml

I'm using Raphael 2.1.0.

When I animate the opacity of a transparent PNG under IE8, the transparency animates well. ie: 'from' an opacity of 0.0 'to' an opacity of 1.0.

After the opacity animation has ended, I want to set/restore the image's position/opacity to a pre-animation state, but the alpha channel of the image becomes opaque. Where there was once a transparent background there is now a white square.

With an SVG renderer - Chrome and Firefox - things are fine. I've tried chaining the image, translation and alpha to no avail.

Here's the code:

```
var element = this._paper.image(image.Url(), 0, 0, width, height);
var removeOnStop = true;
var fromParams = {}
var toParams = {};

// From options
fromParams.opacity = options.from.alpha;
// ...
element.attr(fromParams);

// To options
toParams.transform = 'T300,300';
toParams.opacity = options.to.alpha;      

// Animate
var anim = Raphael.animation(toParams, duration, 'linear', function() {  
    if (removeOnStop) {
        element.attr({ opacity: defaultProperties.alpha });
        element.transform('T' + defaultProperties.left + ',' + defaultProperties.top);
    }
}).repeat(repeat);

element.animate(anim);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the following

- Animating the alpha, everywhere, but this causes null reference issues within Raphael
- Chaining `translate()`/`transform()` and `attr()`
- Applying filters directly to the object
- Changing the order (attr before transform and vice versa)

In the end, the working solution is to translate AND set the opacity using `attr`:

```
if (removeOnStop) {
    element.attr({ opacity: defaultProperties.alpha });
    element.transform('T' + defaultProperties.left + ',' + defaultProperties.top);
}
```

became

```
if (removeOnStop) {                        
    element.attr({ transform: 'T' + defaultProperties.left + ',' + defaultProperties.top, 
                     opacity: defaultProperties.alpha });
}
```

Importantly, you *must* do this when initially creating the image and setting the initial opacity.

I hope this will save people future trouble.

Comment: This works for `.image` elements. I'd hoped it might also work for image fills on paths or other elements, but it seems it doesn't -  any transform seems to kill the PNG transparency for these permanently.